# onchange event dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyCategory", 
                   (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MyCategory, 
                   "SELECT RECYCLABLE ITEM", new { @class = "form-control", 
                                                   onchange = "GetSelectedTextValue()" })
```

I want to send to controller some textbox value upon onchange in dropdownlist but the sending event in ajax always fail

Function:

```
function GetSelectedTextValue() {
    var e = document.getElementById("MyCategory");
    var value = e.value;
    document.getElementById('RecyclableTypeID').value = value;

    $.ajax({
        url: '<%: Url.Action("getall")%>',
        method: "GET",
        contentType: "application/JSON;odata=verbose",
        data: { id: value, RecyclableTypeID : value },
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Ok")
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Fail");
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult getall(int id, int RecyclableTypeID)
{
    return View();
}
```

Model:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public int RecyclableTypeID { get; set; }
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please include in your question.

Comment: I am getting this below error 


Request URL: https://localhost:44336/RecyclableItems/%3C%:%20Url.Action(%22getall%22)%%3E?id=6&RecyclableTypeID=6
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 400 
Remote Address: [::1]:44336
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: `failed to load resource: the server responded with the status 400`

Comment: use `dataType: 'jsonp'` inside `ajax`

Comment: Does the url look correct when the request is sent?  Maybe it is routing through a different controller.